# Unable to modify body font in Outlook email with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I need to preload some outlook email drafts as part of a process. These emails will be sent manually afterwards.

A PowerShell script invokes outlook methods and creates the email. It uses HTML in order to specify the font.

```
# Create an Outlook application object
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
# Create a new mail item
$MailItem = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)  # 0 represents olMailItem, which is for a mail item
# Set properties for the email draft
$MailItem.Subject = "Hello World"
$HTMLBody = @"
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Aptos, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
        color: #000000; /* Change the color as needed */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is the email body text.
  </body>
</html>
"@
$MailItem.HTMLBody = $HTMLBody
$MailItem.To = "recipient@example.com"
$MailItem.CC = "cc@example.com"
# Save the email as a draft
$MailItem.Save()
# Display the draft email
$MailItem.Display()
# Release COM objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($MailItem) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook) | Out-Null
# Clean up
Remove-Variable Outlook, MailItem
```

The outlook window that pops up with `$MailItem.Display()` shows the correct font i.e. Arial, Calibri, etc.  but when opening the draft afterwards, the chosen font isn't rendered. Not displaying the draft won't change this behavior.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to choose $MailItem.Display() after creating the item so I can see what Powershell is doing earlier in the process. I then use the command

```
$MailItem.HTMLBody = $HTMLBody + $mailItem.HTMLBody
```

instead of

```
$MailItem.HTMLBody = $HTMLBody
```

I believe this pulls in my saved signature from HTML emails. Then when you are saving the email to the drafts folder, it should be saving with the font that is input in the variable $HTMLBody.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$MailItem = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$MailItem.Display()
$HTMLBody = @"
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 22pt;
            color: Red
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body> 
    This is the email body text.
    </body>
    </html>
    "@
$MailItem.HTMLBody = $HTMLBody + $mailItem.HTMLBody
$MailItem.To = "recipient@example.com"
$MailItem.CC = "cc@example.com"
$MailItem.Save()
$MailItem.Close(0)
```